# Regular expression to match all but some specific lines of logs

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose, I have following exception:

```
E 180822 133447.332 [pool-9982-thread-1] verylongfoo 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What I need is to match only those exceptions that contain `java.lang.NullPointerException` but lack the `verylongfoo` part.
It ought to be just a Perl 5-compatible regex, not a program written in Perl

I've tried something like

```
.*(?<!verylongfoo)[\s]java\.lang\.NullPointerException
```

and this

```
(?!verylongfoo).*\sjava\.lang\.NullPointerException
```

but neither works.

When a lookbehind matches the unwanted part, it just starts matching from the second letter of it.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Is `java.lang.NullPointerException` really on a separate line?

Comment: In some places - yes, in some it's just a space, but all of that is covered by \s

Comment: You should explain how you are reading the file. If you are testing one line at a time then this cannot work without additional code. But if you are reading the entire file at once then you need a way of isolating individual messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is close, it just needs to be anchored to the beginning of the line and the negative lookahead then needs a `.*` to allow `verylongfoo` to be anywhere in the string:

```
^(?!.*verylongfoo).*\sjava\.lang\.NullPointerException
```

Regex101 demo with single and multi-line strings is [here](https://regex101.com/r/kcA7gd/13).

Comment: That's why I have added the `.*` before `verylongfoo`. If you don't anchor the regex, it can start matching anywhere in the string, for example just after the `v` in `verylongfoo`, so the regex will match all lines in the log.

Comment: https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html
It works here, but not on my server, I have no clue why, Thank you anyway, man!

Comment: No error, just doesn't get any exceps with java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What happens if you just search for `java.lang.NullPointerException`?